# What is the bitwise NOT operator in Rust?

Tags: rust, operators

Looking at the [list of bitwise operators in the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#bitwise-operators), I don't see a NOT operator (like `~` in C).  Is there no NOT operator in Rust?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The [**`!` operator**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Not.html) is implemented for many primitive types and it's equivalent to the `~` operator in C. See this example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc71248cd9f687cb1e43257eb382e529&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
let x = 0b10101010u8;
let y = !x;
println!("x: {:0>8b}", x);
println!("y: {:0>8b}", y);
```

Outputs:

> ```
> x: 10101010
> y: 01010101
> ```

See also:

- [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40467995/155423)

Comment: For the record, now this can be found in the reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#negation-operators

Comment: Now at https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#negation-operators