# How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in Rust?

Tags: rust, bit-manipulation

How do I set, clear and toggle a bit in Rust?

Comment: Are you looking for how to twiddle bits?

Comment: does Rust have bitwise operators?

Comment: Haven't you tried `&`, `|` and `^`? They're all available in Rust.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: It has.

Comment: Then why don't just use what's in the other question?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Like many other languages, the bitwise operators `&` (bitwise AND), `|` (bitwise OR), `^` (bitwise XOR) exist:

```
fn main() {
    let mut byte: u8 = 0b0000_0000;

    byte |= 0b0000_1000; // Set a bit
    println!("0b{:08b}", byte);

    byte &= 0b1111_0111; // Unset a bit
    println!("0b{:08b}", byte);

    byte ^= 0b0000_1000; // Toggle a bit
    println!("0b{:08b}", byte);
}
```

The main difference from other languages is in bitwise NOT, which uses `!` instead of `~`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut byte: u8 = 0b0000_0000;

    byte = !byte; // Flip all bits
    println!("0b{:08b}", byte);
}
```

You can also shift bits left or right:

```
fn main() {
    let mut byte: u8 = 0b0000_1000;

    byte <<= 1; // shift left one bit
    println!("0b{:08b}", byte);

    byte >>= 1; // shift right one bit
    println!("0b{:08b}", byte);
}
```

There are many other conceptual things that ultimately do bit-level manipulation that are not expressed with operators. Check out the [documentation for an integer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i8.html) for examples. One interesting example is [`leading_zeros`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i8.html#method.leading_zeros). Here is how to rotate by a certain number of bits:

```
fn main() {
    let mut byte: u8 = 0b1000_0000;

    byte = byte.rotate_left(1); // rotate left one bit
    println!("0b{:08b}", byte);

    byte = byte.rotate_right(1); // rotate right one bit
    println!("0b{:08b}", byte);
}
```

[The book has some more information](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html)

Comment: Interesting bit about `!` versus `~`. I would probably have tried the latter first.

Comment: @XavierT. yeah, it's definitely different, but IMO it does make more sense in the end. It is just a negation, after all.

Comment: fyi, the notation `"{:#08b}"` is designed to print the '0b' (or '0x', etc) before the binary number

Comment: @Djzin TIL! However, the zero-padding doesn't feel "right"; you actually have to use `{:#010b}` because it's an overall width :-(

Answer (score 13):

Rust has both bit-twiddling operators and binary format printing (very helpful for debugging):

```
fn bit_twiddling(original: u8, bit: u8) {
    let mask = 1 << bit;

    println!(
        "Original: {:b}, Set: {:b}, Cleared: {:b}, Toggled: {:b}",
        original,
        original |  mask,
        original & !mask,
        original ^  mask
    );
}

fn main() {
    bit_twiddling(0, 3);
    bit_twiddling(8, 3);
}
```

It also has the compound assignment variants (`|=`, `&=` and `^=`).

[The book has some more information](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, I'd like to add the following use case: If you have a bitfield like `0b10001000` and you want to update bit 3 in any case to true or false, you can do it like this:

```rust
    const SHIFT: u8 = 3;
    let set_bit_3 = false;
    let bits = 0b10001000;
    let bits = bits & !(1 << SHIFT) | (u16::from(set_bit_3) << SHIFT);
```