# How can I get bit value at positioned index in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to execute the below program.

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: u8 = 0b00000001;
    let b: u8 = 0b10101010;
    let c: u8 = 0b00001111;
    let length = a.count_ones() + a.count_zeros();
    for n in 0..length {
        println!("{}", a[n]);
        println!("{}", b[n]);
        println!("{}", c[n]);
    }
}
```

But I am getting `` error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `u8` ``

Comment: Related: [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40467995)

Comment: Instead of `a.count_ones() + a.count_zeros()` you could also use `mem::size_of::<u8>() * 8` or `mem::size_of_val(&a) * 8`.

Comment: @vallentin `mem::size_of::<u8>()` will _always_ be 1. OP clearly wanted the number of significant binary digits.

Comment: @PeterHall I'm unsure if I'm supposed to read between the lines of anything, but `a.count_ones() + a.count_zeros()` is the same as `mem::size_of::<u8>() * 8`

Comment: Probably `8 * mem::size_of::<u8>() - a.leading_zeros()` is what was intended?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rust doesn't provide indexes into individual bits of an integer. You need to use bitwise operators instead:

This will count from the right (least to most significant bits):

```
fn main() {
    let a: u8 = 0b00000001;
    let b: u8 = 0b10101010;
    let c: u8 = 0b00001111;
    let length = a.count_ones() + a.count_zeros();
    for n in 0..length {
        println!("{}", a >> n & 1);
        println!("{}", b >> n & 1);
        println!("{}", c >> n & 1);
    }
}
```

The reason why this isn't provided is that the [`Index` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) is defined like this:

```
pub trait Index<Idx>
where
    Idx: ?Sized,
{
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

`index()` returns a reference, but references are always to a byte address; you can't make a reference to a single bit.

---

Depending on your actual use case, you may also be interested in one of these crates:

- [`bitfield`](https://docs.rs/bitfield/0.13.2/bitfield/macro.bitfield.html)
- [`bitvec`](https://docs.rs/bitvec/0.19.4/bitvec/vec/struct.BitVec.html).

Comment: And what about byte order? You should check for it.

Comment: Also _technically_ you could implement `Index` you'd just have to return a reference to a const `0` or `1`.

Comment: That is actually true. But you couldn't implement `IndexMut` that way, so it would be a weird kind of half-feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the byte into an array of bits, and then use the array to access the individual bits.

## Convert the byte to a bit array

```
/// Gets the bits of a byte as an array, with the most significant bit
/// at index 0 and the least significant bit at index 7.
/// For example, if the byte is 130, the array will be [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
fn get_bits_of_byte(byte: u8) -> [u8; 8] {
    let mut bits = [0u8; 8];
    for i in 0..=7 {
        let shifted_byte = byte >> i;
        // Get the rightmost bit of the shifted byte (least significant bit)
        let cur_bit = shifted_byte & 1;
        // For the first iteration, the cur_bit is the
        // least significant bit and therefore we place
        // that bit at index 7 of the array (rightmost bit)
        bits[7 - i] = cur_bit;
    }
    bits
}
```

You might use the following inside the function to get a better understanding of its behavior:

```
println!(
    "Index: {i}, shifted byte: {shifted_byte:08b}. Current bit (with shifted_byte & 1): {cur_bit}"
);
```

## Test the function

Here are a few tests, including the example code you provided.

```
#[test]
fn test_get_bits_of_byte() {
    let byte = 0b1010_1010;
    let bits = get_bits_of_byte(byte);
    assert_eq!(bits, [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]);

    let byte = 255;
    let bits = get_bits_of_byte(byte);
    assert_eq!(bits, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);

    let byte = 3;
    let bits = get_bits_of_byte(byte);
    assert_eq!(bits, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]);

    let byte = 130;
    let bits = get_bits_of_byte(byte);
    assert_eq!(bits, [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]);
}

#[test]
fn index_bytes() {
    let a: u8 = 0b00000001;
    let b: u8 = 0b10101010;
    let c: u8 = 0b00001111;
    let length = a.count_ones() + a.count_zeros();

    let a_array = get_bits_of_byte(a);
    let b_array = get_bits_of_byte(b);
    let c_array = get_bits_of_byte(c);

    for n in 0..length {
        println!("{}", a_array[n as usize]);
        println!("{}", b_array[n as usize]);
        println!("{}", c_array[n as usize]);
    }
}
```