# How to modify a bit value at given position in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am able to replace the value with 1 but it is not replacing with 0. Output of below program is `0b11111111` . Ideally it should be `0b11110000`. Please let me know what I am missing here.

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let a: u8 = 0b00001111;
    let b: u8 = 0b11111111;
    let c: u8 = 0b00000000;
    let length = mem::size_of_val(&a) * 8;
    let mut p : u8 = b;

    for n in 0..length {


        if (a >> n & 1) == 0b1 {
            let d = c >> n & 1;
            p = p | (d << n);
        }

    }

    println!("0b{:08b}", p);

}
```

Comment: I believe `p = a ^ b;` will give `0b11110000`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467995/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-rust)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't specific to rust.

```
True | x => True
True & x => x
True ^ x =? ¬x
False | x => x
False & x => False
False ^ x => x
```

So for your values

```
a | b == 0b11111111
a ^ b == 0b11110000
a & b == 0b00001111
```

In terms of your code, you're not doing anything in the case where `a >> n & 1 == 0`. You need to use something like

```
let d = b ^ (1<<n); // switch nth bit - gives something like 0b11101111
p = p & d; // leaves all bits untouched except nth which is set to 0
```