# How do I manipulate binary numbers in Rust?

Tags: rust

How can I handle and do mathematical operations in Rust, such as adding or dividing two binary numbers?

In Python, there is [something like this](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-two-binary-numbers-in-python):

```py
bin(int('101101111', 2) + int('111111', 2))
```

Which works fine unless you need to use floating point numbers.

Comment: Python also has first-class binary literals; you can write `0b101101111 + 0b111111` rather than have to convert them from strings, just as in Rust.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Binary numbers in Rust can be defined using the prefix `0b`, similar to the `0o` and `0x` prefixes for octal and hexadecimal numbers.

To print them, you can use the `{:b}` formatter.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = 0b101101111;
    let y = 0b111111;
    println!("x + y = {:b} that is {} + {} = {} ", x + y, x, y, x + y);

    let a = 0b1000000001;
    let b = 0b111111111;
    println!("a - b = {:b} that is {} - {} = {} ", a - b, a, b, a - b);

    let c = 0b1000000001;
    let d = 0b111111111;
    println!("c * d = {:b} that is {} * {} = {} ", c * d, c, d, c * d);

    let h = 0b10110101101;
    let r = 0b101;
    println!("h / r = {:b} that is {} / {} = {} ", h / r, h, r, h / r);
    println!("h % r = {:b} that is {} % {} = {} ", h % r, h, r, h % r);
}
```

The output is:

```
x + y = 110101110 that is 367 + 63 = 430 
a - b = 10 that is 513 - 511 = 2 
c * d = 111111111111111111 that is 513 * 511 = 262143 
h / r = 100100010 that is 1453 / 5 = 290 
h % r = 11 that is 1453 % 5 = 3
```

Comment: [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40467995/155423); [What is the bitwise NOT operator in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38896155/155423).