# How do I convert an integer to binary in Rust, such that i can iterate over the digits?

Tags: rust, binary

I am trying to convert a decimal i32 in Rust to a binary representation I can manipulate, I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235827/how-do-i-manipulate-binary-numbers-in-rust) that I can print and declare i32 values to and from binary format; but I'm trying implement binary division using logical operators, (as opposed to just using the standard i32 math operators, this is for a leetcode question) and I'm not familiar enough with Rust syntax to understand how I can do this with the [Binary trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Binary.html) that i32 implements, or if there is perhaps a dedicated binary type or iterator that I should be using.

While writing this question, I was able to figure out a workable solution by using the String type like so:

```
fn main() {
    let a : i32 = 5;
    let bin_a = String::from(format!("{a:b}"));
    let bin_s = String::from("101");

    assert_eq!(bin_a, bin_s);
}
```

But this feels clunky and like there's probably a more direct way of iterating over binary representations of numbers, so I'll submit this question in hopes someone more knowledgeable can contribute; thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic operations:

- `(x >> n) & 1` gives you the `n`th bit,
- `x & !(1 << n)` clears the `n`th bit,
- and `x | (1 << n)` sets the `n`th bit.

So iterating over the digits is as simple as `(0..32).map (|n| (x >> n) & 1)` from least to most significant, or `(0..32).rev().map (|n| (x >> n) & 1)` from most to least significant.